# Remove timezone/time element from Date object in Java 11

Tags: java, spring, java-11

I have below string being fetched:

> String dateStr = "Tue Dec 06 00:00:00 EDT 2002";

But when I am parsing using the below `DateFormat` object shown as below

```
 DateFormat myDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
 Date myDate=dateFormatTime.parse(myDateFormat);
```

Even if I try to format or parse the resultant `myDate` object , I am not able to remove the timezone/time constraint from the resultant Date object.

Expected output is  `Date` object of just `DD/MM/YYYY` format only.

Comment: Your code snippet produces a `Date` object, not an output `String`. If you have problems with the output, include the code that produces the output.

Comment: @Holger Yes. Expected outcome is Date object only!

Comment: but (as already commented/answered multiple times on this site) a `java.util.Date`: (i) has no format (just a default format for the return of its `toString()` method); (ii) it represents an instant in time, despite its name - so it always have a *time component*; **(iii)** strongly recommended not to use the `Date`, `Calendar`, `SimpleDateFormat`, ... classes - these were outdated almost 10 years ago (Java 8) by the `java.time` package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1, there's an inconsistency in this string. December 6, 2002, was actually a Friday, not a Tuesday. The "Tue" at the beginning of the string seems to be a mistake.

2,  The newer java.time package (available in Java 8 and later) provides a more robust framework for handling date and time.

```
String dateStr = "Tue Dec 06 00:00:00 EDT 2002";

// Adjust the date string to omit the day of the week.
dateStr = dateStr.substring(4);

DateTimeFormatter parseFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.US);
ZonedDateTime dateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(dateStr, parseFormat);

DateTimeFormatter outputFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy");
String outputDateStr = outputFormat.format(dateTime);

System.out.println(outputDateStr);
```

Comment: it will create the String object only at the end. I wanted to have date object.